# Usage of "Non avere né arte né parte"

Tags: word-usage, meaning, idioms, phrases

I know that this phrase describes someone who has not got any skills and is poor but I would like to understand when it is used for example:  just to say one is penniless, poor or in a more particular way. I am asking this because I want to find the exact English equivalent.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let me quote from Carlo Lapucci, *Dizionario dei modi di dire della lingua italiana*, Garzanti-Vallardi, 1979, p. 13:

> **Non avere né arte né parte**
>   Non conoscere un mestiere, non avere nessuna abilità e non avere né beni né appoggi.
>   Il detto fa probabilmente riferimento alle arti (maggiori e minori), e alle corporazioni medievali delle quali uno faceva parte secondo l'attività che svolgeva. Le corporazioni entravano poi nelle divisioni politiche (parti). C'è anche il detto: “Chi ha arte ha parte”.

That is, «Not knowing a trade, having no skills and having neither goods nor supporters. The saying probably refers to the *Arti* (major and minor ones) [1], and to the medieval guilds of which one was part according to the activity he carried out. The guilds, in turn, were involved in the political divisions (*parti* [2]). There is also the saying: *Chi ha arte ha parte*.»

To add a personal comment as an Italian mother tongue, more than a simply penniless person, I'd say it of someone who is a good-for-nothing, who hasn't a say in anything, nor seems to be able, or willing to.

[1] See for instance the [*Arti* di Firenze](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guilds_of_Florence).

[2] Compare this with “(political) parties”.

Comment: Also, "quel quadro non ha né arte né parte", i.e. "it's particularly bland".